# Why is my ShareActionProvider not clearly outlined and its menus gray?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I'm using a `ShareActionProvider`, defined in code, not xml, on a dark action bar (`Theme.Holo/DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar`).

This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Note that there is almost no visible hint that the share icon and messenger icon belong together. The surrounding box is dark instead of light gray.

Answer (score 3):

When defining the `ShareActionProvider` in code, especially when the action bar is differently themed (in this case because it's dark), you need to use a **themed context**, obtained from the action bar, not just a regular context:

```
final Context themedContext = context.getActionBar().getThemedContext();
ShareActionProvider ap = new ShareActionProvider(themedContext);
menuItem.setActionProvider(ap);
```

Thanks to Adam Powell for pointing that out.